# How to get error report from remote database?

Tags: android, mysql, database, http-post

I am sending a POST request with a bunch of parameters to a remote script which handles my parameters and enters its values into database.

As no parameter is getting written into the database, is there a way to get an error report from the remote database? Just as I am in PHPAdmin or other database IDE and try to enter some SQL command.

Is it possible for a remote PHP script (which handle parameters values) to receive an error report from a database and pass it back to me? I am asking this as I am not a web developer and I do not control the script. I can only ask for some features be implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't anyway that I know of to get an error from a remote session. MySQL has `SHOW ERRORS;` but this is only for your session.

The PHP script can fairly easily check for SQL errors using [`mysql_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) or using the above. The script developer could then have this passed back.

Comment: I thought so. I did not get this info. Is there a lot of work to fetch the error text, convert it to a string or JSON and pass it back? How does its error report look like?

Comment: The error report is just a usual MySQL error. I.e.: "ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'myDB.foo' doesn't exist". I wouldn't have thought it would be too much work but you'd need to check with the author of the script.

Comment: I could handle this. Does a report come in a big string?

Comment: @sandalone Yeah, `mysql_error` returns a string error message. `mysql_errno` can be used to grab the MySQL error number.